# Using Try[Boolean] with list iteration

Tags: scala

```
case class Employee(name :String, dept :String, empId:String, startDate:String)
val emp1 = Employee("abc","accounts", "1234","2019-09-28")
val emp2 = Employee("def","HR", "12345","2019-09-29")
val emp3 = Employee("pp","HR", "12346", "2019-09-28")
val emp4 = Employee("xyz","accounts", "12347","2019-09-20")

val list = Seq(emp1, emp2, emp3, emp4)

def isValidDate(date: LocalDateTime, e: 
   Employee):Boolean={
     date.isAfter(e.startDate)
    }

private def test(name :String, date:String,list:Seq[Employee])={

  list.exists(e =>isValidDate(LocalDate.parse(date).atStartOfDay(), e))
}

test("abc",2019-09-28, list)
test("xyz",2019-09-28, list)
test("def",2019-09-28, list)
```

The above works but when I change method to below

```
def isValidDate(date: LocalDateTime, e: 
   Employee):Try[Boolean]={
     date.isAfter(e.startDate)
    }
```

The below line gives compile error as it expects a boolean

```
  list.exists(e =>isValidDate(date, e))
```

I want the handling of success and failure be outside `isValidDate` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you'll need to change the implementation of `isValidDate`:

```
def isValidDate(date: LocalDateTime, e: Employee): Try[Boolean]={
  Try { date.isAfter(e.startDate) }
}
```

Then, the implementation of your higher order function would need to deal with the `Try`:

```
private def test(name: String, date: LocalDateTime, list: Seq[Employee]) = {
  list.exists(isValidDate(date, _) match {
    case Failure(_) => false
    case Success(value: Boolean) => value
  })
}
```

Or as Zang proposes in the comments:

```
private def test(name: String, date: LocalDateTime, list: Seq[Employee]) = {
  list.exists(isValidDate(date, _).getOrElse(false))
}
```

I would say though, that I'm not sure all this is necessary. Does `isAfter` throw any exception? Try is mostly used to capture *exceptional* code, which I don't think is the case here.

Comment: Why not `isValidDate(date, _).getOrElse(false)`

Comment: The PO explicitly said he wanted to _manage_ the success and failure of it. Your solution is definitely more elegant in this particular case for handling failure. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @hasumedic my bad I have updated the code which can throw exception

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle the exception outside `isValidDate` then there is no point in changing `isValidDate`, you can simply catch the exception outside. For example

```
private def test(name: String, date: LocalDateTime, list: Seq[Employee]) =
  Try {
    list.exists(e => isValidDate(date, e))
  }.getOrElse(false)
```

This will fail the whole test if there is an exception. If you want to ignore exceptions and keep testing later employees, do this

```
private def test(name: String, date: LocalDateTime, list: Seq[Employee]) =
  list.exists(e => Try(isValidDate(date, e)).getOrElse(false))
```

However in this case I believe that it better to put the exception handling in `isValidDate`, even though this is not what you say you want:

```
def isValidDate(date: LocalDateTime, e: Employee): Boolean =
  Try(date.isAfter(e.startDate)).getOrElse(false)

private def test(name: String, date: LocalDateTime, list: Seq[Employee]) =
  list.exists(e => isValidDate(date, e))
```